# Galaxy 3 automatically turns off and on

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

Haven't received any solution after several calls to AT&T Advanced Support, nor Samsung Support! This problem started after the first connection to my hotel wifi, and happens continuously throughout the day, every day! No other wifi connection available.

Attempts to solution I found during research of other helpful websites and support suggestions:

- Turned off and/or uninstalled some apps;
- removed battery for over an hour;
- wifi setting to "Always" maintain connection;
- cleared Cache of some apps, and more;

but none of the above steps helped. Contemplating installation of [WiFi Analyzer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.farproc.wifi.analyzer) reviewed to be the best and most downloaded for troubleshooting. Not sure if it's true or will help.

The issue arises when:

- After installing apps or updating some current ones, phone usually turns off again. When this happens throughout the day, my WiFi completely turns off!
- It also happens when composing long texts, emails, other tasks, before completion and sending, resulting in losing everything I've done!
- Also having problems with emails not automatically and periodically saving as drafts during composing, as it should and previously did!

I have spent numerous hours re-typing important lost communications. I still don't know if the cause is due to WiFi, apps, the phone itself, or anything else. I definitely need help because I'm thousands of miles away from home, completely alone, and my cell phone is the only way to connect with family, and conduct necessary business (except for expensive hotel room phone)!  I will be so grateful and appreciate any and all help and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The WiFi Analyzer will not help you. It's only used to test and show information for the wireless signals around you. I found a forum with several suggestions, one will probably work for you. Click [here](http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s3/320524-help-s3-keeps-restarting.html) to go to it. There are many things that could be causing the issues (too many for me to list) but they cover many troubleshooting techniques there that might save you a trip to a service shop and get your S3 back up and running in a couple of hours. Good luck!